# Can you copy location metadata from one photo to another in iPhoto?

Tags: photos.app

Some of my imported pictures don't have location data on them because they were created using apps like Diptic. I'd like to tag them with them location data but the 'Assign a place...' search dialog in iPhoto is doing a poor job of finding the location the photos were taken.

I have pictures in my iPhoto library that have the exact location information that I'd like to assign to these location-free photos.

Is it possible to copy just the location metadata from some pictures to others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's very simple.

1. **Select** the photo you want to copy the location data from and hit CMD+C to copy
2. Right click the photo you wish to paste the location
3. Select **'Paste Location'** from the contextual menu.

Also you can check out http://thedigitalstory.com/2009/04/copy_and_paste_geoda.html for a pictorial guide.

Comment: I never would have seen that. I never right-click/cmd-click on things...thanks.

Comment: Bounty's have to sit for 24 hours before they can be awarded, but rest assured it's coming your way.

Comment: Does not seem to work under iPhoto's successor "Photos" any more, unfortunately.